# R HTML output instead of table in markdown

Tags: r, for-loop, html-table, r-markdown, knitr

I have the following block of code -

```
for(provider in unique(summary_data$Provider.Resource)){
  provider_appts = summary_data[summary_data$Provider.Resource == provider,]
  output_table = table1(~ Type | Appt.Status*Appt.Len, data=provider_appts, caption = provider)
  as.data.frame(output_table)
}
```

The output in the notebook if I run it is what I would like - a nice, clean table1 output as the screenshot below shows.
[Screenshot of desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBVlO.png)

The thing is, when I run the code in notebook format, it also gives a list of shiny.tag tables that I can click on, which are the names under Provider.Resource.

When I run the markdown, the output is an html format, see screenshot below as a snippet of the example.
[Markdown example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykW0R.png)

I feel like I'm close. What's missing?

I tried piping through Kable, using kable_styling, and other suggestions on google search, but nothing is giving the desired output.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping results in `print()` and set `results = 'asis'` in code chunk options, like ````{r code-chunk, results = 'asis'}`?

Comment: Yes, I did and the output is still html coding.